# inline jquery in joomlas 3 view

Tags: jquery, model-view-controller, inline, joomla3.1

How do I add an inline jquery javascript to components view in joomla 3. If I add it like `<script>my javascript mixed with <?php echo $myvariable ?></script>` is causing blank page and the debuger shows nothing. Than I've been trying to use the offered example in the documentation but I have markup problem with it

```
<?php
$document = JFactory::getDocument();
$document->addScriptDeclaration('
    window.event("domready", function() {

    });
');
?>
```

what is the proper way to use it in joomla3

Answer (score 0):

You are using it right, but thats no jQuery. Try this:

```
$document = JFactory::getDocument();
$document->addScriptDeclaration('
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        //do stuff
    });
');
?>
```